# What does php middleware refers to?

Tags: php, middleware

Sorry if you are upset that this is not a very specific question but I researched online and couldn't find out what PHP middleware refers to?
I have seen this term used in the Slim microframework and laravel framework and I really need an explanation.
Thanks a lot

Comment: Did you search? https://mwop.net/blog/2015-01-08-on-http-middleware-and-psr-7.html ;)

Comment: Thanks,that was pretty helpful ;)

Answer (score 3):

I'm no tremendous expert but i can try to explain it. Basically middleware in l5 and up replaces filters that were in place on older laravel versions. It adds verification to either a route/controller or the whole site. It will run whatever logic you have in a middleware before rendering a specific page to the user. For instance, laravel comes with an auth and csrf middleware upon installation. The auth middleware will check if the user is authenticated BEFORE showing a page and csrf verifies on everything and makes sure your current token matches what is present on the db.

To create a middleware you need to php artisan make:middleware NameofMiddleware.

A middleware can either be per each route or for the whole application.

Comment: Thanks,I think I got the basic idea

Comment: Np glad it helped a little